# TextInputLayout hint dissapears

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I used TextInputLayout to wrap TextInputEditText and when I click the edit text to start typing the hint dissapears instead of appearing above the line.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/animaldisc_et"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/breed_et">
            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Description"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.503"
                 />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
android:id="@+id/input_layout_password"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/input_password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/hint_email" />
```

Plain & simple.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine the hint is not is disappearing it may be due to your colors combinations of the **TextInputLayout** and background try using some vibrant colors.

[Your Code Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tx7Xn.png)

modified it a bit and put it inside linear layout.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_gravity="center"

        android:id="@+id/animaldisc_et"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Description"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.503"
            />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
```